# Android HTTP Connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

Can anybody tell my why this doesn't work in the Android emulator? From the browser I have access and the server is internal. All I can think of is that I'm missing some configuration on my app so it can access the network layer.

```
try {
    InetAddress server = Inet4Address.getByName("thehost");
    //Doesn't work either
    //or InetAddress server2 = Inet4Address.getByAddress(new String("192.168.1.30").getBytes());

    if(server.isReachable(5000)){
        Log.d(TAG, "Ping!");
    }

    Socket clientsocket = new Socket(server, 8080);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Server Not Found");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't open socket");
}
```

**Throws an UnknownHostException**

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As far as configuration goes, the only setting you should need to access the Internet from your application is the INTERNET permission, enabled by adding the following line *outside* the Application tags within your application Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So the manifest would follow this general construction

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.android.apis">    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application 
    android:name="MyApplication"    
    android:label="@string/application_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_icon">
    [ .. Your Activities go here ]
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

It might still  not work, because of the timeout. Since you need root permissions to send an ICMP Package and the implemetation of isReachable will use the slow TCP version of ECHO. Chekcout the javaDoc.