# Android Freebase Query IOException

Tags: java, android, ioexception, freebase, mql

I am attempting a simple Freebase Query within Android, Eclipse.  I believe the URL compiles correctly, as I can copy/paste the encoded URL, copy/paste it into a browser and it pulls up the correct result. The line HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute... is throwing an IOException.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
String query = "{\"type\":\"/user/tsegaran/language/phrase\",\"id\":null,\"name\":\"Affidavit\",\"/user/tsegaran/language/phrase/translation\":[]}";
String testQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
String testQuery1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=" + testQuery + "&key=" + API_KEY;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(testQuery1));
JSONObject response = (JSONObject)parser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
String jsonResults =  response.getString("result");
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonResults).nextValue();
String name = object.getString("/user/tsegaran/language/phrase/translation");
...
```

**Here is a better formatted version of my Stack Trace:**

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
 org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
 org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
 org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
com.example.nworthen_androidpoc.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:60)
com.example.nworthen_androidpoc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My exceptions were not consistent (NullPointer, IOException, NetworkonMainThread). I added the posted code to an AsyncTask.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting output on my Logcat anymore, but when debugging it kicks me to:** 
Class File Editor

Source not found
The JAR file C:/users..... has no source attachment.  You can attach the source...
// Compiled from ThreadPoolExecutor.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)

```
public class java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor extends java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService {

  // Method descriptor #17 (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue;)V
  // Signature: (IIJLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue<Ljava/lang/Runnable;>;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 7
  public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit, java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue workQueue);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
```

...

Comment: The stack trace of the thrown IOException would help people diagnose this problem.

Comment: This seems like it has turned into separate question about how to use AsyncTasks. Are you still getting IOExceptions when querying Freebase from the code you posted above? If you're now getting NullPointerExceptions from calling your AsyncTask you should repost that as a separate question with the relevant code and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure that your app has permission to access the Internet?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/442590/81821

Comment: Shaw, thank you for the suggestion.  I believe it moved me forward. I have progressed from an IOException to: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject